# Migrating Local Filezilla Server to SharePoint

Tags: file, server

My company currently has a local FileZilla server that we use to share and store pretty  much all of the company files. Primarily for the  project managers and accounting department. I'm wondering what would be best way to get everything up and running onto SharePoint, other than manually uploading everything?

I have experience with Linux server administration so I'm not scared of the command-line. Any help and guidance would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to use SharePoint Online, Microsoft purchased [mover.io](https://mover.io/connectors/) which has connectors for (S)FTP to help you perform that migration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

Using OneDrive & Sharepoint for business for this case:

Here's the guide I'm following:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/fileshare-to-odsp-migration-guide

with this tool: https://spmtreleasescus.blob.core.windows.net/install/default.htm

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct, if you believe that it is. This will help future users, if this question turns up in a search.